# BindingResult doesn't work - Spring Test

Tags: spring, testing, spring-mvc

I have my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addtimesheet", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTimeSheet(@ModelAttribute("timesheet")TimeSheet timeSheet,
                         BindingResult bindingResult,
                         ModelMap model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        if (bindingResult.hasFieldErrors("horaInicio")){
            model.addAttribute("messageHoraInicioError",HORA_INICIO_INVALIDA);
        }
        if (bindingResult.hasFieldErrors("horaFim")){
            model.addAttribute("messageHoraFimError",HORA_FIM_INVALIDA);
        }
        return TIMESHEETCRUD_NOVO;
    }


    return TIMESHEETCRUD_LIST;
}
```

when I try:

/timesheet/addtimesheet

with the field "horainicio = null", my bindingResult.hasError() is true.

Well, It's work :-)

My test:

```
@Test
@ExpectedDatabase("timeSheetControllerIt.xml")
public void novoTimeSheetSemHoraInicial() throws Exception {
    TimeSheet novoTimeSheet = new TimeSheet();
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/timesheet/addtimesheet")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body(super.convertObjectToFormUrlEncodedBytes(novoTimeSheet))
            .sessionAttr("timesheet", novoTimeSheet)
    )
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("timesheetcrud/novo"))
            .andExpect(forwardedUrl("/WEB-INF/views/timesheetcrud/novo.jsp"))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("messageHoraInicioError", is("timesheetcontroller.horainicio.invalida")));
}
```

I saw in my controller that object "timeSheet" is "horaInicio" null, but my bindingResult.hasErrors() is false.

Anybody have idea what's wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Does your default constructor set everything to null?

Comment: No, but when I debug, my object is: timeSheet.horaInicio = null :-(

Comment: It's work now. My controller was not @Valid ;-) thanks